# Matrix-type Django admin for two-dimensional data

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Suppose you have a two-dimensional data model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    # ... more metadata

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    # ... more metadata

class Value(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

So this is essentially the normalized version of a matrix of data:

```
    | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 
 -----------------------
 B1 | 5  | 9  | 2  | 1
 B2 | 8  | 3  | 3  | 8
 B3 | 4  | 9  | 5  | 7
 B4 | 2  | 6  | 2  | 7
```

Is there a way to easily present this matrix in a Django admin, such that it can also be edited easily in case many values in the matrix need to be updated simultaneously?

Comment: I'm tempted to just stick up a "No" answer. I suspect you'll have to build that kind of functionality yourself.

Comment: @JohnMee I'm not looking for a ready-made solution, but rather to discuss ways to implement this. If you do not have meaningful insight to add, feel free to exclude yourself from the discussion.

Comment: @YuvalAdam, I'm curious to know what solution you came up with, if any.